# Understanding Stack Overflow's "unanswered" questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

When I navigate to the "Unanswered" section, it displays a list of questions, but those questions have answers.

What does "unanswered" question actually mean? 0 answers OR user yet to accept the answer?

I found it the answer: "questions with no upvoted answers"

Comment: right @TimSullivan

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score -3):

user yet to accept the answer, but some time it happens that one ask question and forgot to 
mark the answered by accepting

Comment: No mate actually I found the answer 'questions with no upvoted answers'

Comment: yes, that's the obvious thing, i included that another scenario